# Editing a date+time field converts to text

Tags: excel, date-formatting

I have formatted a (Excel 2010 spreadsheet) column as 
"ddd\ dd-mmm-yy\ \ hh-mm\ \h\r\s"
which shows the existing data as "Sun 04-Oct-15  17-30 hrs" format.

When I try to edit the date or the time, the cell content shows as "04 10 2015 05:30:00 PM".  So far so good.

Now when I try to change the date or time (say, change it to 5-Oct), the data in the cell seems to convert to text !!!

Whatever I try, this does not convert to date format except if i delete the time portion (retaining the date portion) of the cell content.  I have been updating this file since the year 2010. And I have never encountered this earlier !!

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Seems as if someone has changed the short date format of your Windows system to `dd mm yyyy`. That's not a good idea since then the date delimiter is a space. Excel will not detect `04 10 2015` as a date. Can you back change this? See http://www.sysprobs.com/change-date-format-windows-7-ddmmyyyy.

Comment: I had changed the short date format to "ddd dd-MMM-yyy". Just reverted back to dd-MMM-yy.    This solved my problem.  Thanks Axel.